# How do I get a list of available NamedCache objects from ScaleOut StateServer (SOSS)?

Tags: c#

I'm using v4.0.

**Update:**

I've hacked together this so far:

```
public class AllFilter : IFilter
{
    #region IFilter Members

    IndexCollection IFilter.GetIndexCollection()
    {
        return new IndexCollection();
    }

    MatchOptions IFilter.GetMatchOptions()
    {
        return MatchOptions.MatchAll;
    }

    #endregion
}

public class CacheMonitorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var results =
            from result in ApplicationNamespace.GlobalNamespace.Query(new AllFilter()).OfType<StateServerKey>()
            group result by result.AppId;

        var b = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            var cache = CacheFactory.GetCache(result.Key);                
            b.AppendLine(cache.Name);
        }

        return this.Content(b.ToString(), "text/plain");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the name of the cache always comes up `null`, even though there is certainly a name when the cache is created. The name certainly needs to be identifiable in the UI, so I need a way to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is no way to do this in v4.0 - the keys for both the stores themselves, as well as the keys for the values are stored as hashes (in the form of `uint`s), so unless the NamedCache is retrieved using the actual name, the name cannot be known.

The only alternative would be to track the string values of the keys in another store in the cache.

According to Mark Waterman from ScaleOut software, the ability to retrieve the names will be available in v5.0, which is due to be released spring 2009.